# Amazon Redshift way to do PostgreSQL to_json and array_to_json

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

In PosgreSQL I am able to do some queries to convert some result rows in JSON or JSON array.
For example if I have a table user:

```
name   surname
----------------
name1  surname1
name2  surname2
name3  surname3

SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(user))) AS users FROM user;
```

Giving as result:

```
                  users
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"name":"name1","surname":"surname1"},"name":"name2","surname":"surname2"},{"name":"name3","surname":"surname3"}]
```

In Redshift I have tried with `LISTAGG` but the only result I could get was 3 rows with a json in each but not what I wanted:

```
              users
------------------------------------
{"name":"name1","surname":"surname1"}
{"name":"name2","surname":"surname2"}
{"name":"name3","surname":"surname3"}
```

Is there a way of doing this in Redshift?

Comment: can you tell us a bit more about your use case - why are you trying to do this? to see if there is another approach?

Comment: @JonScott, I am trying this because I have a big query divided into subqueries that some give multirow result and others only one, so what I need it's to create json from each one, so the result is a row of json results, because if not, I would get an error of subquery gives more than a result.